# Storing the class type in a bean

Tags: java, generics

I have a ThreadPool class that has a method add which takes a `Runnable` and a number of milliseconds as a task to schedule:

```
public static void addScheduler(Runnable r, long millis) {
 //scheduling code
 //now I want to save it to check later
 ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask();
 st.setTaskType(r.getClass());
 st.setFrequency(millis);
 persistentes.add(st); //this is an ArrayList<ScheduledTask>
}
```

Now I want to store the task info to an ArrayList to check it later, but when I save the information of the task, and check the taskType, it is always java.lang.Class. I understand this is because java type erasure, but is there a way to store the type of the class?

This is my ScheduledTask class:

```
public class ScheduledTask {

    private Class<?> taskType;
    private long frequency;

    public Class<?> getTaskType() {
        return taskType;
    }

    public void setTaskType(Class<?> taskType) {
        this.taskType = taskType;
    }

    public long getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(long frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return taskType.getClass().getName()+ ": " + (frequency / 1000) + " seg.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your mistake is that you call `getClass()` one too many times:

```
public String toString(){
    return taskType.getClass().getName() + ": " + (frequency / 1000) + " seg.";
}
```

`taskType` is the class you're looking for (such as `MyTask`). Its (raw) type and what is returned by the superfluous call to `getClass()` is `java.lang.Class`.

```
public String toString(){
    return taskType.getName() + ": " + (frequency / 1000) + " seg.";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create the new instance using newInstance() and can check the type (using instanceof operator). You can also get the name of class using getName() and use String comparison

Comment: Can't see how this answers the OP's question.

Comment: @milkplusvellocet The op's q is talking about *checking the tasktype*. I am assuming that there are diff type of tasks and check is required that what type of task is there. If intention is just to print the name of task than, getName() will suffice.

Comment: 'You can create the new instance using newInstance().' Why create a new object just to check the type information that's already available. 'Can check the type (using instanceof operator).' Which types would you check for using instanceof?

Comment: If you will use instanceof directly, should not you get false as the object is of type Class.